# How to print List() in @RestController Response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-4

I've a controller in a Spring App with this Code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseObject index(){
    System.out.println(this.sf);
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    List<Project> projects = session.createQuery("from Project").list();
    session.close();
    System.out.println(projects);
    return new ResponseObject(projects);
}
```

I've tried to return `List<Project>` and also my new created Object `ResponseObject` with this code:

```
public class ResponseObject {
    protected Object data;
    protected Object error;

    public ResponseObject(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Object error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

But in all cases my JSON Reponse looks like: `{"data":[{}],"error":null}`.

`Projects` output is : `[Project{id=1, name='Digital project'}]`

Can anybody tell me why my List is not included in the JSON? Thanks!

Comment: did you check - how many projects are actually inserted when performing : ession.createQuery("from Project").list() ?

Comment: Hoi Gerrit ;-)
Check out this: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337319/object-design-for-rest-result-including-error-handling. I asked a question about ResponseObjects a while ago, maybe this works for you

Answer (score 0):

`protected Object data;`

Change to

`protected List<Object> data;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a ResponseEntity like :

```
return new ResponseEntity<List<Project>>(projects, HttpStatus.OK);
```

see http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Provided you have Jackson in the classpath, which if you're using Spring boot you do everything will be de-serialized correctly.  You do not need the ResponseObject class.

Comment: it easier to do with: `new ResponseEntity(list, HttpStatus.OK)`